# Is it feasible to freeze a whole pig?

Tags: food-safety, meat, freezing, pork

How long can I freeze a pig whole? How can I keep it from getting freezer burned?

We are having a wedding in September and it's June but the pig is already currently at the size we need it to be. I was told that the pig will get freezer burned by then.

Comment: I would be most interested to know what kind of freezer equipment you have. Anything less than commercial grade and I would stongly advise against trying to freeze a whole pig.

Comment: @RichardtenBrink Can you articulate why? What about the wide consumer stand-alone freezers? Do commercial freezers _freeze_ better?

Comment: @Insane I should think that they generally freeze colder and are bigger and are less prone to temperature fluctuations.

Comment: @Catija Cool, just wondering

Comment: @Insane commercial freezers for quick freezing (a) run *much* colder than a home fridge; (b) have fans to further speed cooling. For storage, they also run colder.

Comment: Are you planning on cooking it whole?  If so, you'd have to freeze it whole ... which would make thawing it interesting, too.

Comment: Are you going to butcher the pig yourself?  Are you planning to cook pig whole?   I am not getting how a bigger pig in Sep is a problem.  Just don't serve the whole pig.

Comment: @Joe - obviously from my answer I was assuming that they planned to cook it whole.  (Why else try to freeze it whole?)  But you're right: defrosting a whole pig is most easily carried out in a commercial chiller too.  Without that option, I'm guessing they'll not be using their bathtub for a few days...

Comment: @Paparazzi : it also affects cooking time ... and if it'll fit in whatever they're planning to cook it in.  (if they're not digging a hole for it ... they might be using a 'china box' or similar)

Comment: @Paparazzi - I obviously don't know the OP's reasons, but keep in mind that pigs grow *really fast*.  If the desired pig is now relatively small, in 12 weeks it could easily gain over 100 lbs.  That's a lot of expensive feed to pay for if you don't want a bigger pig, you need the equipment to deal with a pig that large, and the meat won't be as tender.

Comment: my suggestion is to fin another pig that can be ready in time for the wedding and keep this one for yourself; butcher it and store in small chunks.

Comment: @Joe They might be doing a lot of things.  That is why I directed the question to the OP.

Comment: @Athanasius  Correct we don't know.  That is why I asked to OP.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the comment by Richard ten Brink: you can't really do this in a home freezer and expect good results.  Even with a large home chest freezer, it will take *way* too long for a whole carcass to freeze all the way through.  Freezing requires a lot more energy than maintaining something that's already frozen, and the process for a pig carcass would probably take several days (depending on the size of the pig).  You'd likely get significant quality degradation during the freezing process itself: slower freezing means more damage to cells, which affects meat quality when defrosted, not to mention that it could take many days for the interior to freeze solid (which could also impact quality).

And "freezer burn," by the way, isn't necessarily caused by long storage: it's the result of poor packing, usually combined with temperature cycling in a freezer, which allows air near the surface of food to lead to oxidation and dehydration.  Yes, a poorly packaged food will get worse over time, but a properly packaged food will last years in the freezer with no freezer burn.  (For a whole hog, you'll need a large chest freezer at home, preferably one without an auto-defrost cycle.)

Anyhow, my personal recommendation would be to seek out a local meat packer or meat processor with access to a commercial freezer.  (Perhaps there's someone who people take game meat to for processing or something?)  Ask them if they'd be willing to freeze the carcass after slaughter and vacuum seal it for you.  The vacuum sealing will significantly help to prevent freezer burn.  I don't know whether vacuum packing is feasible depending on how large the pig is (many processors only do it with small whole pigs), but that would be your best bet.

They'd also be able to advise you on the feasibility of freezing a larger pig for that long if they can't vacuum seal it.  But my guess is that it should be fine for a few months if you can keep it consistently below 0F and away from temperature cycling.

Comment: Are there any consumer-in-_price_ commercial freezers? Might be worth noting why it would be impossible (or not) (due to cost) for someone to just buy one themselves. Obviously I don't mean getting a walk in freezer installed in your home.

Comment: @Insane - It's not just the "commercial" status of the freezers, but their overall size and power.  There are relatively small commercial freezers like you'd find in a small restaurant (which aren't *that* pricey).  But they also wouldn't really be the best way to freeze a whole pig -- they simply wouldn't have the necessary power to freeze it as quickly as a meat packer's larger freezer.

Comment: Ah, I got ya :-)